# Split the sentence into two half using css and display in text field

Tags: html, css

I have few big sentences that i need to split and display two lines but the sentences are coming from server I am not able to use **br** tag or other tag, now sentence is display only half and another half is not displaying only.

```
.TextBox {
    width: 96%;
    height: 25px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px 2%;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #555;
    max-width:200ch;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: Could you please give us an example of the html and css?

Comment: .TextBox {
    width: 96%;
    height: 25px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px 2%;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #555;
    max-width:200ch;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

Comment: Edit your question and add these infos

Comment: but the sentence is not splitting, half sentence is not displaying.

Comment: Why don't you just use `min-height: 25px` instead of setting the height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use an input field for showing the html. An input field is only one line (example 1). If you want to use multiple lines just use a textarea (example 2).

Example 1:

```css
.TextBox {
    width: 96%;
    height: 25px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px 2%;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #555;
    max-width:200ch;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<input id="idSeqQue" type="text" readonly name="firstname" data-role="none" class="TextBox" placeholder="Given" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." />
```

Example 2:

```css
.TextBox {
    width: 96%;
    height: 100px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px 2%;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #555;
    max-width:200ch;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="idSeqQue" type="text" cols="10" readonly name="firstname" data-role="none" class="TextBox" placeholder="Given">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."</textarea>
```

Comment: <input id="idSeqQue" type="text" readonly name="firstname" data-role="none" class="TextBox" placeholder="Given "> this is my html

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Added **`display:table`** which is the cleanest solution. See updated demo.

---

Wrapping text by CSS you can try 3 properties.

**`white-space`, `word-break`,** and **`word-wrap`**

**Details  in demo**

### Demo

```css
p {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.whiteSpace-Nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.whiteSpace-Normal {
  white-space: normal;
}

.wordBreak-BreakAll {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.displayTable {
  display: table
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <h5>{white-space: nowrap}</h5>
  <p class='whiteSpace-Nowrap'>You might have <code>white-space:nowrap</code> which makes text ignore the border and continue going.</p>

  <h5>{white-space: normal} or {word-break: normal} or {word-wrap: normal}</h5>
  <p class='whiteSpace-Normal'>will make text wrap normally at the spaces between spaces. But if there's a long word like: supercalifragilisticexpialidocious that exceeds the width of it's container, it will only wrap at a hyphen. Sup-er-cal-i-fra-gil-is-tic-ex-pi-al-i-do-cious</p>
  <hr>
  <p style='border:0;width:100%;'>If you are having problems with long words, then you can use hyphens like the previous example, or try the following:</p>

  <h5>{word-break: break-all} or {word-wrap: break-word}</h5>
  <p class="wordBreak-BreakAll">breaks between any letters. It doesn't care where. So a word like: pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis is chopped up and served in a thousand pieces.</p>
  <hr>

  <h5>{display:table}</h5>

  <p class='displayTable'>behaves like a &lt;table&gt; so text will wrap and the container will expand vertically once text has reached it's limit horizontally.</p>

  <p style='border:0;width:100%;'>The paragraph above and below have identical properties. The only difference between them is that the bottom paragraph has a long unbreakable word.</p>

  <p class='displayTable'>A long word like: Antidisestablishmentarianism will not break out of the border. Instead, it will accommodate that unbreakable word by expanding.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `word-wrap: break-word;' , 'word-break: hyphenate;'

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
  
.demo-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.demo-2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="demo-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut odio temporibus voluptas error distinctio hic quae corrupti vero doloribus optio! Inventore ex quaerat modi blanditiis soluta maiores illum, ab velit.</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="demo-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut odio temporibus voluptas error distinctio hic quae corrupti vero doloribus optio! Inventore ex quaerat modi blanditiis soluta maiores illum, ab velit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not working for me, here u have defined sentence but i dono for me which sentence will come and length

Comment: <input id="idSeqQue" type="text" readonly name="firstname" data-role="none" class="TextBox" placeholder="Given "> this is my html